# Force tablet to be in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-orientation

Is there a way to force the tablet to be in landscape mode as default orientation when the user start's my app. Is there a way to do this with theming or something like that, so the user doent see orientation change when he is starting the app?

***Note: the same app is (should be) in portrait mode for phones***

For now I have a boolean values folder refs.xml(both values and values-large) with different value for tablet and phone, but the user can see that the app is rotating
Code:

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {   
        return (context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet));
    }
```

Comment: In general I wouldn't recommend you do this. Forcing a particular orientation breaks the UX and I'm not the only person to find it very annoying to the point that I don't use apps which do it. Why don't you just create layouts for the different orientations and let the users use their devices the way they want too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if (isTablet(getApplicationContext())) {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);



**//this method for check having run in tablet or not??**

     public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
         return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Landscape does not mean this is tablet. You should put `isTablet` for tables in XML file stored in `res/values-sw600dp` instead.

Comment: I have used this approach in of my projects and it worked well. I've also added isTablet to values-sw720.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `screenOrientation` in your `activity tag` in `manifest.xml` as below :

```
<activity>
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
</activity>
```

And you application will open in `landscape` mode

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in `Manifest` file where you define your `activities`

```
<activity
            android:name="com.yourpackage.ActivityClassName"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

add below line in your manifest under activity tag...

```
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```