# Force website to landscape mode when the phone or mobile device is landscape (bootstrap)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show my website landscape when phone is landscape. is it possible ? im using bootstrp and when u brosw it on safari it automatically landscape when the orientation is landscape but on my app which gets what on the website it only allow portrait can you please help me force landscape the website when its landscape

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you force a website to be in landscape mode when viewed on a mobile device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761487/how-do-you-force-a-website-to-be-in-landscape-mode-when-viewed-on-a-mobile-devic)

Comment: @ObsidianAge No its not duplicate read my post and the difference with that post.

Comment: See the word 'possible' in my automatically-generated comment. And although the question is different, the accepted answer in that post **directly** answers your question. Do your research before opening new questions. Also look into the post linked in the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only